# Customizing w2ui sidebar vertical scrollbar with JScrollPane

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, w2ui

I'm trying to customize the w2ui sidebar's scrollbar with JScrollPane jQuery plug-in, but I fail all the times and by saying that I mean that I couldn't make JScrollPane to change the sidebar scrollbar style. So, could you please share snippet code here that shows how to get it done ?

Thanks.

It is what I've tried:

```
$(w2ui['sidebar'].box).find('.w2ui-sidebar-div').jScrollPane({
    horizontalGutter:5,
    verticalGutter:5,
    'showArrows': false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried several libraries and at the end 'slimScroll' was actually the one which worked perfectly :

```
onRefresh: function(event) {
  event.onComplete = function () {
    $('.w2ui-sidebar-div').slimScroll({ height: '100%' });
  }
}
```